# Assigning the function output to a variable

Tags: c++, function, arduino, return, output

I have a function which returns the address of a 4x2 matrix whose name is 'a'. 
This function computes the elements of 'a' matrix inside and returns the address of the matrix. When I use that function, I want to assign its output to a matrix called 'a1' but when I do so, 'a1' becomes a zero matrix. However, when I assign the output to the same 'a' matrix, everything works fine. Can anyone help me? The code is written on Arduino IDE.

```
double a[4][2], a1[4][2];
double T0E[4][4]={
  {0.1632, -0.3420, 0.9254, 297.9772},
  {0.0594, 0.9397, 0.3368, 108.4548},
  {-0.9848, 0, 0.1736, -280.5472},
  {0, 0, 0, 1}
};

const int axis_limits[4][2]=
  {
    { -160, 160 },
    { -135, 60 },
    { -135, 135 },
    { -90, 90 }
  };
  const unsigned int basex = 50, basez = 100, link1 = 200, link2 = 200, link3=30, endeff=link3+50;

double *inversekinematic(double target[4][4])
{

  // angle 1
  a[0][0] = -asin(target[0][1]);
  a[0][1] = a[0][0];
  if (a[0][0]<axis_limits[0][0] || a[0][0]>axis_limits[0][1] || isnan(a[0][0]))
  {
  bool error=true;
  }

  // angle 2
  double A = sqrt(pow(target[0][3]-cos(a[0][0])*endeff*target[2][2], 2) + pow(target[1][3]-sin(a[0][0])*endeff*target[2][2], 2));
  double N = (A - basex) / link1;
  double M = -(target[2][3]-endeff*target[2][0] - basez) / link2;
  double theta = acos(N / sqrt(pow(N, 2) + pow(M, 2)));
  a[1][0] = theta + acos(sqrt(pow(N, 2) + pow(M, 2)) / 2);
  a[1][1] = theta - acos(sqrt(pow(N, 2) + pow(M, 2)) / 2);

  // angle 3
  for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) 
  {
  a[2][i] = {asin(-(target[2][3]-endeff*target[2][0]-basez)/link2-sin(a[1][i]))-a[1][i]};
    }

  // angle 4
  for(int i = 0; i <=1; i++)
    {
      a[3][i] = {-asin(target[2][0])-a[1][i]-a[2][i]};
      }
      return &a[4][2];
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  a1[4][2]={*inversekinematic(T0E)};
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'll just give up.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `return &a[4][2];` you are returning the address of the 3rd element of the 5th row. This is out of bounds, since C++ uses zero-based indexing and the array was declared as `double a[4][2];`. I think what you want to do is just `return a;` to return the address of the entire matrix.

Also, you're doing lots of strange things like declaring the parameter `double target[4][4]` with a size and using initializer lists to assign single elements, which look unusual to me.

I'll try to be a little more detailed. In C/C++, arrays are nothing more than pointers. So, when you assign one array to another array you are making them literally point to the same data in memory. What you will have to do is copy the elements with loops, or perhaps use `memcpy(dest, src, size)`. For example, if you want to *copy* the contents of `double a[4][2]` to `double b[4][2]`, you would use something like `memcpy(b, a, sizeof(double) * 8);`. If you use `a = b;` then `a` and `b` are pointing to same locations in memory.

Comment: which would also fail because he is apparently trying to assign an array to another array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am new to this as you noticed. I couldn't make return a; work, it said 'cannot convert 'double (*)[2]' to 'double' in return'. But I passed 'a' matrix as global and used memcpy() and it worked just fine. When I didn't declare double target with size, I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:
1. your code says the function `inversekinematic()` returns a pointer to a `double`, not an array.
2. you return a pointer to a `double`, but it's always the same address.

Maybe typedefs will help simplify the code?

```
typedef double Mat42[4][2];

Mat42 a, a1;

Mat42 *inversekinematic(double target[4][4])
{
        // ...
        return &a;
}
```

But, for the code you've shown, I don't see why you need to return the address of a fixed global value. Perhaps your real code might return the address of 'a' or 'a1', but if it doesn't ...